# JAVA standalone application throws java.net.SocketException while calling to soap web service

Tags: java, jar, timeout, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have a standalone java application (JAR file). And also I have another SOAP web service. I've generate above web service's client through wsimport as a jar file and included as a library for my standalone java application.Now I am calling the soap web service through my standalone java application. I am running this standalone  java application inside a Linux server. Some web service requests send from my java application complete within few seconds, but some requests take more time to complete since there is lot of data to process.  When it takes more time to complete the request my standalone java application throws an exception as  **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**. But web service completes its task without any exception.
Inside my java standalone application I have set timeout as below.

// Set connection timeout to 3 minutes

`((BindingProvider) commonInsDailyChargingService).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", 3*60*1000);`

// Set receive timeout to 15 minutes

`((BindingProvider) commonInsDailyChargingService).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", 15*60*1000);`

Even with this timeout settings same exception throws. 
I really appreciate your suggestions for fixing this issue.

Comment: You need to help people help you: update your question with the code that you're using, and _the complete stack trace_ from the exception.

Comment: Usually "connection reset" means that the server closed the network connection without reading all the data you had sent in the request. This would be a bug in the SOAP web service, not in your Java application. It's hard to say more without seeing the code and network traffic captures.